# Non atomic caching

Tags: java, android, caching, bitmap

Was going over this [official android article](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap) regarding bitmap caching.

I was wondering regarding the architecture presented in this article:

```
public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    final String imageKey = String.valueOf(resId);

    final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder);
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(mImageView);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    ...
    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                getResources(), params[0], 100, 100));
        addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }
    ...
}
```

loadBitmap checks if the cache exists, spins off an async task, and that task put's the image in the cache.

I'm wondering whether this is risky as it's not atomic - and you have one component checking the cache, and another one putting stuff in the cache. Would it be better to either

1. move the existence check to the doInBackground; or
2. create some other way where the entire interaction would be: `Bitmap bitmap = getFromCacheOrDecode(key);`

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not risky, because it turns out it is atomic. As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache), `LruCache` is thread-safe. The UI thread will always be able to "see" any prior modifications made to `mMemoryCache` by `doInBackground()`.

There is a little bit of a race condition in `addBitmapToMemoryCache()`, where a second background worker could add a bitmap to `mMemoryCache` after the first background worker verified that `getBitmapFromMemCache()` returned `null`, but this is of little practical consequence.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. LruCache get and put methods are used with synchronized, so you don't need to worry about multithreading. Sorry it took me so long to get back to this :-)